# How do I extend Azure's Contoso Insurance demo to use custom authentication?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

The [Contoso Insurance sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/contosoinsurance/) shows a lot of great examples, however I want to create a custom authentication method that would plug in-line with the following [code](https://azure-samples.github.io/ContosoInsurance/).

```
 internal static async Task<ProviderCredentials> GetCurrentCredentialAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, IPrincipal user)
    {
        var principal = user as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var claim = principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider");
        if (claim == null) return null;

        var provider = claim.Value;
        ProviderCredentials creds = null;
        if (provider.IgnoreCaseEqualsTo("microsoftaccount"))
            creds = await user.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>(request);
        else if (provider.IgnoreCaseEqualsTo("facebook"))
            creds = await user.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>(request);
        else if (provider.IgnoreCaseEqualsTo("aad"))
            creds = await user.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>(request);
        return creds;
    }
```

I want to implement this on the MVC app, and on the mobile app.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - it contains information on authentication for both mobile and MVC apps.

Your main problem will be your custom auth will not be integrated into the /.auth/me endpoint, and thus you won't be able to get the information from the `GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<>()` method.  You will need to write a custom library that works with your custom authentication scheme for this.